# Highcharts: Is there a way to set colors by category names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have two charts one is a spline graph and one is column graph. They have some categories common so what I want to do is set the same colours for the same category names in both the graphs.

Since both are dynamically driven I don't which category will come at which position at which graph. Also searching category name and setting colours is not an option because the performance is most important.

Although I can set hard coded colours for all the category names. I don't know if that's possible. I've heard of 'Zones' (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones) but I don't know how to set colors by category names. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by categories of spline chart? Is it about multiline chart - and every line is a category - or is it about single-line chart and `categories` on `xAxis`?

Comment: I am not sure what you would like to achieve. It is possible to use zones with categories just like every other axis type. http://jsfiddle.net/dzdyuxuq/

Comment: Ya so instead of the value (which is the position for the category names) I want to define colors by category names (a string). is something like this possible http://jsfiddle.net/akasheg/d4cz2wbd/1/

Comment: I think it is almost the same, your categories are positioned in x values (from 0) so you should be able to get x value connected with specific category

Comment: ya but that's the problem in my case the positions of the category names won't be fixed for the 2 graphs i'm using. So one will different color and one will show different depending on what positions those categories get added. So I need to somehow use the color by the 'category names'

Comment: So why you don't want to make different zones in different charts? I think that you should be able to get category position in categories array for both charts.

Comment: getting positions dynamically for categories and setting colours for each one of them for all the other charts I have will make the performance more bad than it already is.

Comment: So maybe you can make wrapper similar to an example below: http://jsfiddle.net/b638bhyn/1/

And for performance issues I can suggest using boost.js module